# when to use multithreading in iOS development?

Tags: ios, multithreading

beside heavy processing, should multithreading mainly be used when you have a not quite responsive UI? or does it have other considerations?
How can I know if my application *should* have multithreading or not?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The use of threading in ios is to ensure hussle-free and seamless experience by the end-users.
You can implement thread whenever you want to extract some resource over the network such as parsing or data retrieval and you don't want the ui to be affected as application would run on main thread and the web-operation on your custom thread.

You may want to use the thread when you need to have concurrent operations or simultaneous such as in game when you hae to have multiple animations on same object at same time.There can be quite a large number of scenarios which may need threading.

You may read [Concurrency Programming Guide By Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

and [Thread Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)

but threads may be an overhead in the application as it needs memory allocation and large operations on thread may affect the performance so use it when it can't be avoided.

You can use NSThread,NSOperations to create threads .GCD is deprecated now.

Comment: GCD is definitely **not** deprecated! If anything, NSThreads should be avoided in favor of GCD or the NSOperation/OperationQueue classes that support blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in `iOS` development `Threads` are used when you don't want to affect you `UI` by a `process` which will take long time to complete. for example when you make a `connection` to parse xml,json,image data etc then you don't want to stop user `interaction` at that time you can use `threads`.

you can start a thread by using `NSThread`.

Things to have in mind before using threads -

- You should never do a graphical change in a thread. If you need to
  that in a thread then you can do only on `main thread`.
- Never use a    `NSTimer` in a secondary `thread`, because your `thread` may
  complete       before `timer` execution so timer may not run.

whenever you want to perform a long `process` then you can use `thread`.

Comment: @trinithis - no it ain't, bucko.

Comment: Right, it's called lots of booze on my part. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Important Application of thread in ios is during network communication.Whole your app is communication with server and if you want to show busy view on UR UI you need to create thread in such scenario to perform network communication in background thread.

In IOS 5,You can opt for GCD(Grand Central Dispatch)Instead of thread to perform same functionality..